# Crash log from Apple approval team

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa, crash

Apple has rejected my app because it crashes and I can't find a way to know where the problem is. They say that the crash was on an iPhone 4 with iOS6.

I have built the archive with Xcode 4.4 and iOS 5.1. I have already upgrade to Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6. As you will see, Xcode doesn't identify the symbols on every line of the stack trace; in particular, the system function names are missing, maybe due to the update and not the same version on my computer; I don't know.

I'm just unable to reproduce this crash, I don't have an iPhone 4, just a 3GS and have no bugs.

Here is the log:

```
Incident Identifier: 23FCC6BC-FB56-4681-8254-E72A01891A80
CrashReporter Key: 1378004e4baa9919d5598a6dec7f08d687552155
Hardware Model: xxx
Process: Myapp [598]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/31F1CD56-357C-4969-8DBA-F19E7D2AF638/Myapp.app/Myapp
Identifier: Myapp
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2012-09-26 14:40:48.221 -0700
OS Version: iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread: 0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation 0x3403129e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3380397a objc_exception_throw + 26
2 CoreFoundation 0x34031158 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96
3 Foundation 0x38ff62aa 0x38f86000 + 459434
4 UIKit 0x36c55776 0x36b66000 + 980854
5 UIKit 0x36c54fca -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3390
6 CoreFoundation 0x340349c0 0x33f6f000 + 809408
7 CoreFoundation 0x33f8bfe6 0x33f6f000 + 118758
8 UIKit 0x36d7372e -[_UIDelayedPresentationContext finishDelayedPresentation:] + 182
9 GameKit 0x32c1dd28 __41-[GKRemoteViewController setupRemoteView]_block_invoke_0327 + 20
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x3840a11a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x384094b2 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x3840adc6 0x38408000 + 11718
13 CoreFoundation 0x34004f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
14 CoreFoundation 0x33f77eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
15 CoreFoundation 0x33f77d44 0x33f6f000 + 36164
16 GraphicsServices 0x34ce02e6 0x34cdb000 + 21222
17 UIKit 0x36bbd2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
18 Crossibus 0x0003cc96 main (main.m:16)
19 Crossibus 0x0003cc4c start + 36


Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32d00350 __pthread_kill + 8
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380db11e pthread_kill + 54
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3811796e abort + 90
3 libc++abi.dylib 0x38c0dd4a abort_message + 70
4 libc++abi.dylib 0x38c0aff4 default_terminate() + 20
5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x33803a74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6 libc++abi.dylib 0x38c0b078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7 libc++abi.dylib 0x38c0b110 std::terminate() + 16
8 libc++abi.dylib 0x38c0c50e __cxa_throw + 118
9 libobjc.A.dylib 0x338039ba objc_exception_throw + 90
10 CoreFoundation 0x34031158 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96
11 Foundation 0x38ff62aa -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
12 UIKit 0x36c55776 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 166
13 UIKit 0x36c54fca -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3390
14 CoreFoundation 0x340349c0 __invoking___ + 64
15 CoreFoundation 0x33f8bfe6 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 282
16 UIKit 0x36d7372e -[_UIDelayedPresentationContext finishDelayedPresentation:] + 182
17 GameKit 0x32c1dd28 __41-[GKRemoteViewController setupRemoteView]_block_invoke_0327 + 20
18 libdispatch.dylib 0x3840a11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
19 libdispatch.dylib 0x384094b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
20 libdispatch.dylib 0x3840adc6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 222
21 CoreFoundation 0x34004f36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
22 CoreFoundation 0x33f77eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
23 CoreFoundation 0x33f77d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
24 GraphicsServices 0x34ce02e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
25 UIKit 0x36bbd2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
26 Crossibus 0x0003cc96 main (main.m:16)
27 Crossibus 0x0003cc4c start + 36

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32d00d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b25e8 pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 44
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x38417eb0 _dispatch_queue_wakeup_global_slow + 72
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x384097da _dispatch_wakeup$VARIANT$up + 106
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x38417a24 _dispatch_queue_push_list_slow2 + 16
5 libxpc.dylib 0x3742a820 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 828
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x38419df4 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$up + 120
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x3840995a _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 82
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x3841a06a _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$up + 150
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x38418212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x384183b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
11 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b2a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
12 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b28a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32cf0648 kevent64 + 24
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x384194ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x3840bdf4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 3 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit._UIViewServiceXPCProxy 0x1ededbb0 target:<_UIQueueRedirectingProxy: 0x1ed77750; target: <_UIViewServiceFencingControlProxy: 0x1ed82fc0; target: <_UIViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy: 0x1ed678e0; target: <_UIObjectArgumentReplacingProxy: 0x1ed6ef60; target: <_UIStrongToWeakAdapter: 0x1edae420; target: <GKRemoteAuthenticateViewController: 0x1ed6c490>>>>; suspension count: 0>; queue: 0x3bebd580 (com.apple.main-thread)>
Thread 3:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x33800f2a objc_release + 10
1 XPCObjects 0x37d9fc66 __destroy_helper_block_133 + 18
2 libsystem_blocks.dylib 0x3427bab0 _Block_release + 220
3 libxpc.dylib 0x374256c4 _xpc_connection_call_reply + 28
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x38409996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x38409890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x38418212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x384183b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b2a0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b28a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name: WebThread
Thread 4:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32cefeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32cf0048 mach_msg + 36
2 CoreFoundation 0x34006040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3 CoreFoundation 0x34004d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4 CoreFoundation 0x33f77eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5 CoreFoundation 0x33f77d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6 WebCore 0x34d5ba70 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380bd30e _pthread_start + 306
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380bd1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x32d00d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b2cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b2a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x380b28a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000 r1: 0x00000000 r2: 0x00000000 r3: 0x3be7e534
r4: 0x00000006 r5: 0x3be7eb88 r6: 0x1ed61194 r7: 0x2fdc4a14
r8: 0x1ed61170 r9: 0x00000300 r10: 0x1ed65e20 r11: 0x36ffaa2f
ip: 0x00000148 sp: 0x2fdc4a08 lr: 0x380db123 pc: 0x32d00350
cpsr: 0x00070010
```

Can you provide any insight into what's wrong or how to determine what's wrong?

Edit:
I think i have found, it was a problem with Game Center and IOS 6. The method "authenticateWithCompletionHandler" is deprecated and make it crash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your 3GS works fine and its running iOS 6, right?

2) You don't need to switch completely to Xcode4.5 if you don't want to for some reason, just install it side by side with Xcode4.4.1 and just use it to test and run your app in a Retina iPhone simulator.

3) If you still cannot get the crash, then I am going to make a wild guess that this is your problem:

```
5 UIKit 0x36c54fca -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3390
```

Is the presentedViewController retained in a strong variable (if using ARC), or in a retained property in the presenting ViewController? If not make it so, but then, no way to know for sure if it fixes the problem.

---

A good reason to build up points here is to be able to add a bounty for an answer - I believe 50 points is the min. Assuming you know Android well (given last name, isn't going to make you friends here in iOS land), answer a few question now and get some points.

With a bounty, you maybe can get someone to test your app on their phone by building an Ad Hoc version of the app (but Provisioning H*ll awaits :-( )

Comment: For beta testing, help make provisioning somewhat easier, and collecting crash info I highly recommend http://testflightapp.com

Comment: 2)I have done the upgrade, the guy who edited my post has turned things like i had the choice but it's already done. 3)Apple say me the steps to reproduce the crash, just start the application and click on a button that call a new controller. I'm not sure or don't really understand what a strong reference can do in this case. It's very basic calling a new controller, it must be just a little later when the controller load something, maybe the admob banner.